# GeoCoding using JSON.NET and the NuGet Googlemapsapi library

Tags: google-maps, json.net

I'm playing around with the Google Maps .NET API available from NuGet, and have gotten stuck on the Geocoding part where queries come in.

In the following code, I'm trying to pass an address to the API and return a `Location` with the matching latitude and longitude

```
public Location GeoCode(string address)
{
    GoogleMapsApi.Entities.Geocoding.Request.GeocodingRequest geoRequest = new GeocodingRequest();

    geoRequest.Address = address;

    GoogleMapsApi.Entities.Geocoding.Response.GeocodingResponse geoResponse = GoogleMapsApi.GoogleMaps.Geocode.Query(geoRequest);

    GoogleMapsApi.Entities.Geocoding.Response.Result geoResult = geoResponse.Results.OfType<?> (?)

    return geoResult.Geometry.Location;
}
```

I realize this is very specific, and I'm happy to expand on the question for a more general application, if someone will enlighten me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GeocodingResponse.Results` is an `IEnumerable<Result>`.  So you just need to do `.First()` to get the first `Result` from it.

```
 var geoResult = geoResponse.Results.First();
```

Note that this will throw an exception if there is no first result.  You will need to handle this case in your code.